# how to set the user data path in tauri/rust

Tags: javascript, rust, desktop, tauri

I was looking for away to set the path for user data path (localstorage, Indexeddb) in tauri is this possible because its possible in electron. I basically want to use Indexeddb but I want to save user data in custom location.

Comment: https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/window/struct.WindowBuilder.html#method.data_directory

Comment: The Short Answer is : yes;
For details See These Links: https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/discussions/4876 and also I found this plugin(didn't try yet): https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri-forage

Comment: can you provide an example on how to change the data directory, I can't find a straight forward way to do it, this shouldn't be this convoluted.